# XML to CSV: Print lines for each child node and sometimes child node is missing

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I need the XML below converted to csv. This was tricky for two reasons: 1) There are multiple Support_Order_Detail child elements and a separate line is needed for each child 2) There are no Support_Order_Detail child elements in the second record. I used preceding-sibling matching on Support_Order_Detail and used the not[] function to handle the record without Support_Order_Detail node. I've included the XSLT that I've struggled with and it does work. I get the correct output. However, I know there is a better way and I do get an error in my debugger:

Ambiguous rule match for /Report_Data/Report_Entry[2]
Matches both "Report_Data/Report_Entry[not(Support_Order_Detail)]" 
and "Report_Data/Report_Entry"

I'm hoping to learn if anyone can suggest where I would not have duplicate code, i.e. two templates. I'd like to get rid of the one using the not[] function.

```
Doe,Jane,Child Support,Mandatory,12345
Doe,Jane,Child Support,Mandatory,12345
Dole,Bob,Student Loan,Federal,56789
```

.

```
    <Report_Data>
      <Report_Entry>
          <Worker>
              <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
              <First_Name>Jane</First_Name>
          </Worker>
          <Lien_Type>Support Order</Lien_Type>
          <Lien_Sub_Type>Mandatory</Lien_Sub_Type>
          <Support_Order_Detail>
              <Support_Type Descriptor="Current Child Support">
                  <ID type="Support_Type">CS</ID>
              </Support_Type>
          </Support_Order_Detail>
          <Support_Order_Detail>
              <Support_Type Descriptor="Past Due Child Support">
                  <ID type="Support_Type">PDCS</ID>
              </Support_Type>
          </Support_Order_Detail>
          <Case_ID>12345</Case_ID>
      </Report_Entry>
      <Report_Entry>
          <Worker>
              <Last_Name>Dole</Last_Name>
              <First_Name>Bob</First_Name>
          </Worker>
          <Lien_Type>Student Loan</Lien_Type>
          <Lien_Sub_Type>Federal</Lien_Sub_Type>
          <Case_ID>56789</wd:Case_ID>
      </Report_Entry>
    </Report_Data>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
     xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
     version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <File xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">
            <xtt:class xtt:name="dateformat" xtt:dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Data/Report_Entry"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Support_Order_Detail"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Support_Order_Detail" >
        <Record xtt:separator=",">
            <LastName xtt:maxLength="14"><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Worker/Last_Name[1]"/></LastName>
            <FirstName xtt:maxLength="17"><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Worker/First_Name[1]"/></FirstName>
            <LienType>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::Lien_Type[1] = 'Support Order' and Support_Type/@Descriptor = 'Current Child Support'">
                    <xsl:text>Child Support</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::Lien_Type[1] = 'Support Order' and Support_Type/@Descriptor = 'Past Due Child Support'">
                    <xsl:text>Child Support</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Support_Type/@Descriptor"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </LienType>
            <LienSubType><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Lien_Sub_Type[1]"/></LienSubType>
            <CaseID xtt:maxLength="20"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Case_ID"/></CaseID> 
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Data/Report_Entry[not(Support_Order_Detail)]" >
        <Record xtt:separator=",">
            <LastName xtt:maxLength="14"><xsl:value-of select="Worker/Last_Name"/></LastName>
            <FirstName xtt:maxLength="17"><xsl:value-of select="Worker/First_Name"/></FirstName>
            <LienType><xsl:value-of select="Lien_Type"/></LienType>
            <LienSubType><xsl:value-of select="Lien_Sub_Type"/></LienSubType>
            <CaseID xtt:maxLength="20"><xsl:value-of select="Case_ID"/></CaseID> 
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected XML results:

```
    <Record xtt:separator=",">
        <LastName xtt:maxLength="14">Doe</LastName>
        <FirstName xtt:maxLength="17">Jane</FirstName>
        <LienType>Child Support</LienType>
        <LienSubType>Mandatory</LienSubType>
        <CaseID xtt:maxLength="20">12345</CaseID>
    </Record>
    <Record xtt:separator=",">
        <LastName xtt:maxLength="14">Doe</LastName>
        <FirstName xtt:maxLength="17">Jane</FirstName>
        <LienType>Child Support</LienType>
        <LienSubType>Mandatory</LienSubType>
        <CaseID xtt:maxLength="20">12345</CaseID>
    </Record>
    <Record xtt:separator=",">
        <LastName xtt:maxLength="14">Dole</LastName>
        <FirstName xtt:maxLength="17">Bob</FirstName>
        <LienType>Student Loan</LienType>
        <LienSubType>Federal</LienSubType>
        <CaseID xtt:maxLength="20">56789</CaseID>
    </Record>
```

Comment: This is confusing, because (1) your stylesheet does **not** generate CSV and (2) it references nodes that do not exist in your XML, e.g. `CF_ADP_Site_ID`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The Workday extension xtt (XML to text) will turn the resulting XML to a csv when processed in Workday app. You're right though, the direct results of the XSLT above will create a new xml doc in order to allow the xtt to convert to text. CF_ADP_Site_ID lines should not have been included. I caught another mistake. I also forgot to include last line in the first template: <CaseID xtt:maxLength="20"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Case_ID"/></CaseID> and in the last: <CaseID xtt:maxLength="20"><xsl:value-of select="Case_ID"/></CaseID>

Comment: Since you are asking about XSLT, I suggest you post the XML result you expect to get as the result of your XSL transformation. -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Yes, of course. First timer mistakes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know about whatever extension or tool you're using, but doing this in pure XSLT is pretty straightforward; match all the `Report_Entry` elements, and if they have any `Support_Order_Detail` elements loop through all of them except the `last()` one (because we've already generated a line for that):

(I've slightly modified this to use a variable instead of the duplicative selects)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="//Report_Entry">
        <xsl:variable name="row">
            <xsl:value-of select="Worker/Last_Name" />,<xsl:value-of select="Worker/First_Name" />,<xsl:value-of select="Lien_Type"/><xsl:value-of select="Lien_Sub_Type"/>,<xsl:value-of select="Case_ID"/>
            <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="$row" />

        <xsl:for-each select="Support_Order_Detail[position() != last()]">            
            <xsl:value-of select="$row" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>


</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9B/1

Answer (score 0):

> I do get an error in my debugger:
>
> Ambiguous rule match for /Report_Data/Report_Entry[2] Matches both
>   "Report_Data/Report_Entry[not(Support_Order_Detail)]" and
>   "Report_Data/Report_Entry"

The error can be eliminated if you change:

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Data/Report_Entry">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
```

Similarly, you can replace:

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Data/Report_Entry[not(Support_Order_Detail)]" >
```

with:

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry[not(Support_Order_Detail)]" >
```

A match pattern is not a select expression: it does not need to include a path, unless the pattern is ambiguous without it (e.g. if you have `Report_Entry` at different places or levels and need to treat them differently.

---

As for "better" code to achieve the same result, this is largely a matter of personal preference. IMHO, if you have two types of `Report_Entry` and each one needs to be handled differently, having separate template to handle them is the best approach, unless the difference is minimal (not your case).

I would look into simplifying the `xsl:choose` block, though.

Comment: Thanks, @micheal.hor257k! I appreciate your opinion on having two templates. I find it easier to mentally parse having two templates. But I appreciate @Dan Field solution. It's cleaner - no duplication. The code I have is even more complex than what I've posted (of course), but summed up what I'm trying to accomplish. I have, as you suggested, simplified my when statement. Thanks again!